# Mobile Menu requires Jquery 2.0.1 but other site scripts require an older version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a website which the client is very happy with, however in IE 8 and older the website is totally broken.

This is because the Jquery version (2.0.1 - which seems to be required by the mobile menu script I'm using) doesn't seem to work with IE 8 and older. If I comment out the menu and change the Jquery version to 1.8.3 it's perfect, but I need the mobile menu for mobile devices etc.

The website is http://www.simonbutlerskiing.com

Any ideas of how I can use 1.8.3 but still retain the menu?

Kind regards
Liam

Comment: What about using multiple jQuery versions? http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

Comment: The heart of that blog post is to use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: jQuery 2.x by design supports only IE9 and higher. the parallel version that supports IE8 is 1.9 and higher. So instead of 1.8.3 try using 1.9.x and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 2.x doesn't work on IE8 and below, period.  They dropped support for IE8/7/6 with the release of 2.0 which is why they continue to maintain 1.10.x as well.

You can either get another off-canvas mobile menu script (they are a dime a dozen) that relies on an older version of jQuery or try to figure out some conditional way to load the script and appropriate jQuery version (e.g. server-side user agent sniffing / browser detection) since you don't need a mobile menu in Internet Explorer anyway.